# How to make PHP return "1 + 2 = 3", and not just 3?

Tags: php

How to make PHP reutrn "1 + 2 = 3"? and not just 3

```
function show_sum($a, $b) {
return "$a + $b = " $a + $b;
}
echo show_sum(1,2);
```

I have already tried:

```
return '$a + $b' = " . $a + $b;
```

I just get 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work. I think the problem is mixing string values and numeric values. I've made everything a string.

```
<?php
function show_sum($a, $b) {
$sum = $a + $b;
$return_string = "$a + $b = " . $sum;
return $return_string;
}
echo show_sum(1,2);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the concatenation operator. Your return statement should be:

```
return "$a + $b = ". ($a+$b);
```

Comment: You're right, it needs parenthesis.  Order of operations causes the string portion to concatenate with $a.  PHP then attempts to add 3 to a string, which defaults to NULL and ultimately returns 3.

Answer (score 1):

Put the result into brackets.

```
function show_sum($a, $b) {
    return "$a + $b = " . ($a + $b);
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. (Also how could you even post an answer when the question was closed?!)

Comment: Panther broke the internet.